# Updated :Robot-state-publisher causing error in tf..with eg. code

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: I am getting ready to open a ticket on the robot state publisher if no one can point out a specific problem with the urdf file. So please if anyone has any ideas please let me before I do this.

Update: simplified urdf that exhibits problem

The following launch file and simple urdf of a box with wheels when run produces tf errors generated by the robot state publisher. If this is a problem in the urdf can someone please point it out. I reduced this to as simple a problem eg as I can. Hopefully someone can see the issue here.

```
The error:[ERROR] [1379637817.041486892]: TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "left_wheel" from authority "/robot_state_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
[ERROR] [1379637817.041663265]: TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "right_wheel" from authority "/robot_state_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)





 <launch>
 <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find rrbot_description)/urdf_error/rrbot.urdf" />

  <!-- Show in Rviz   -->
  <node name="rqt_gui" pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui"/>

  <node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" 
        name="joint_state_publisher" output="screen">
        <param name="use_gui" value="True"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" 
        name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
  </node>


</launch>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="rrbot">

   <link name='base_link'>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <origin xyz="0 0 .1 " rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box  size=".4 .2 .1"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
  </link> 

  <link name="left_wheel">
    <collision name="collision">
      <origin xyz="0.05 0.15 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
         <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <origin xyz="0.05 0.15 0.1" rpy="0 1.5707 1.5707"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder  length="0.05" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint type="revolute" name="joint1">
    <origin xyz="0.05 0.08 0.05" rpy="1.5707 1.5707 0"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <axis>
         <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
     </axis>
     <limit upper="0" lower="-1.57" velocity="10" effort="10"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79151/updated-:robot-state-publisher-causing-error-in-tf..with-eg.-code/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-13**:
Have you checked to output of the publisher? Maybe switch it to debug.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-13**:
I will down load and compile source and put set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug) in CMakefile...I think this is all I need to do..yes...as long as my catkin paths are frist in env.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-14**:
I meant the ROS logger debug. You can set that with rxloggerlevel for each running node. Also you should look at the robot_state_publisher outputs or logfiles, not the master log -- this still doesn't guarantee you'll get usefull results. Someone must have implemented that.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-14**:
All he data I've posted comes form the logs...so that is it.  There is nothing in the rxlogger that is not also in the log files , no? If there is no other way of getting additional data then with out turning on new debug features then what you see is what I got.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-14**:
This output looks to me like the output from the rosmaster. You'd be interested in the output of robot_state_publisher as that's causing your problems.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-20**:
Can you try, if the errors in your example still appear when you use revolute instead of continuous joints?

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-09-20**:
Yes...same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened a ticket on this issue

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2013-12-11**:
For those interested, the ticket is here: https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/4 .